# Why the linux driver file is much smaller than that in windows?

Tags: linux, drivers

Recently I install a graphic device driver in Linux, I found that is only dozens of KB. But that is dozens of MB in windows. I wonder why?

Comment: What driver? What files did you compare exactly?

Comment: Some Windows drivers come packaged with large userspace utilities while their Linux counterparts do not. Are you counting those utilities in your size measurements?

Comment: For example, graphic device it looks really small, but in windows it's much bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel drivers for Linux (the .ko files) will only handle hardware access as well as some basic functionality.

For graphics drivers, that would be

- text mode
- framebuffer graphics mode (including simple 2D acceleration like "copy this area")
- an interface to the render command queue

all of these can be implemented in a few kilobytes, especially when other components are reused.

Complex operations like OpenGL rendering, Shader compilation and submission, etc. are not handled in the kernel, as that would jeopardize system stability. Rather, these are handled in a separate process, usually either the X server or a program using 3D graphics, and then a list of commands is sent to the driver, which simply passes it on to the card. Again, this driver heavily reuses components.

Under Windows, the philosophy is to squeeze all of this into the kernel module (.sys) as there is no benefit from componentizing (the various vendors do not generally work together).

Answer (score 0):

well that would be because most of the driver files required will actually be there in Linux so that's why not many files required for that graphic device.
where as for Windows, those device drivers might not be included in the core so that's why more driver files are required. Hence, Bigger size.